# How to make virtualkeyboard not shown when EditText gets focus?

Tags: android

I want to show a DatePicker when `EditText` gets `focus` :

```
public class DatePickerUtil {

    private Context ctxt;
    private Calendar calendrier = Calendar.getInstance();
    private EditText chp;
    private KeyListener keyListener;
    private OnTouchListener touchListener;
    private boolean canceled;
    private DatePickerDialog picker;

    public DatePickerUtil(Context context, EditText field) {

        ctxt = context;
        chp = field;

        keyListener = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public int getInputType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content,
                    int states) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

        touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    canceled = false;
                    show();
                }
                return false;
            }

        };
    }

    private void show() {
        OnDateSetListener evt = new OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int annee, int mois, int jour) {
                if (!canceled) {
                    calendrier.set(annee, mois, jour);
                    chp.setText(DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", calendrier));
                }
            }
        };
        picker = new DatePickerDialog(ctxt, evt, calendrier.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                                        calendrier.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                                        calendrier.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        picker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, ctxt.getResources().getString(R.string.button_cancel), new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    canceled = true;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        picker.show();
    }

    public void attache() {
        chp.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        chp.setKeyListener(keyListener);
    }
}
```

At runtime the focus is not inside the `EditText` but just surrounds the field :

[image]

As you can see the user cannot edit the `EditText`'s content , so the `virtualkeyboard` is not necessary. The problem is that the `virtualkeyboard` is shown when the `EditText` gets `focus` ! So how to make it not shown when the `EditText` gets `focus` ?

Comment: Did you try with `android:inputType="date"` in your xml?

Comment: yes , but Android has a default format of `DD/MM/YYYY` , although my format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok use this method

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null)
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity
                    .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: You can put this method in a class, change it to static and call from any where you need to hide kerboard

Answer (score 0):

Try This Programmatically

```
YourEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
YourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bascically you can translate any date using something like :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = format.format(Date.parse("Your date string"));
```

So then you can detect when the user selects a date, and display the version you want to work with.

See here for more : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Well it will not actually remove the keyboard, but instead the user will be able to enter a date, which you'll be able to convert to whatever format you want/need

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Edittext to TextView and add the onclick listener for the view and show the datepicker dialog for the same like below:

```
    private DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMin;
    mTvDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);

            }
        });


@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
            mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, mYear,
                    mMonth, mDay);
            mDatePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
            return mDatePicker;

        }
        return null;
    }

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            mDay = selectedDay;
            mMonth = selectedMonth;
            mYear = selectedYear;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String selectedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            mTvDate.setText(selectedDate);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside edittext onclicklistener method.this will force keyboard to hide.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```